# Create table from join SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I am running the query :

```
select 
    [temp_table_excel_insert_for_join].person_id,
    [temp_table_excel_insert_for_join].city,
    city.city_id
from 
    temp_table_excel_insert_for_join, city
where 
    temp_table_excel_insert_for_join.city = city.city
```

without problem now I want to have all these columns as a new table so I used

```
create table mytable as 
( select 
      [temp_table_excel_insert_for_join].person_id,
      [temp_table_excel_insert_for_join].city,
      city.city_id
  from 
      temp_table_excel_insert_for_join, city
  where 
      temp_table_excel_insert_for_join.city=city.city)
```

but it did not work for me what should I do to make it happen? I don't want to create a view I want to have a table.but I am not familiar if I should do a left join or other things

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to create a new table `mytable` with the columns `person_id, city, city_id` then use the `select ... into` syntax:

```
select 
    [temp_table_excel_insert_for_join].person_id,
    [temp_table_excel_insert_for_join].city,
    city.city_id
into 
    mytable 
from 
    temp_table_excel_insert_for_join
inner join 
    city on temp_table_excel_insert_for_join.city = city.city
```

Note that this will fail if you run it more than once as the table already would exist and you would have to drop it first.

[See the documentation for more information on the into clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx)

Comment: @RenelChesak The question and my answer refers to Microsoft SQL Server, not Oracle, so your comment regarding PL/SQL is not applicable. For MS SQL Server this is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select [temp_table_excel_insert_for_join].person_id
       , [temp_table_excel_insert_for_join].city
       ,city.city_id
  into mytable 
  from temp_table_excel_insert_for_join inner join city on temp_table_excel_insert_for_join.city=city.city)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the two operations. First:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable ( etc)
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( <List of columns to insert> )
SELECT <Columns to insert>
FROM etc
WHERE etc
```

Answer (score -1):

This works if you remove the brackets after your AS clause - at least in SQL Lite. So you can just write:

```
 CREATE TABLE mytable AS
 SELECT 
      [temp_table_excel_insert_for_join].person_id,
      [temp_table_excel_insert_for_join].city,
      city.city_id
  FROM 
      temp_table_excel_insert_for_join, city
  WHERE 
      temp_table_excel_insert_for_join.city=city.city;
```